# Are You Entitled To Release From Prison If All Of Your Accusers Recant Their Testimony?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, appeal, criminal-procedure, perjury

There's no physical evidence that a man convicted of a murder in Addison, Ill. is guilty. Instead, his conviction is mostly based on the testimony of three friends, all of whom later recant.

May a federal court vacate the murder conviction and order that he be freed from prison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A federal court may not vacate the conviction which the state court declined to vacate under these circumstances.

> On March 22, 2009, a jury found Luis Villavicencio‐Serna guilty of
> first‐degree murder of Armando Huerta Jr. Scant physical evidence
> linked him to the charge. The conviction instead was largely based on
> testimony from three of his friends, all of whom later recanted.
>
> Villavicencio‐Serna exhausted his state‐court appeals and then sought
> a writ of habeas corpus pursuant to 28 U.S.C. § 2254(d). Throughout
> these proceedings, he consistently has challenged the sufficiency of
> the evidence to support his conviction. He emphasizes the lack of
> physical evidence connecting him to the murder, and he suggests that
> several factors - inconsistencies between the testimonies of his three
> friends, their subsequent recantations, and the interrogation tactics
> used by the police—reveal that the police pressured his friends to
> implicate him. Finally, he offers an alternative theory that links
> another group to the murder.
>
> In the face of these arguments, the Illinois Appellate Court upheld
> his conviction. The [federal] district court, applying the double‐layered
> deference required by section 2254(d), concluded that the state
> court’s decision was not unreasonable, and so it refused to issue the
> writ. *See Villavicencio‐Serna v. Melvin*, No. 17 C 5442, 2019 WL
> 2548688 (N.D. Ill. June 19, 2019).
>
> Although we sympathize with the district court’s observation that “the
> lack of any physical evidence in this case is troubling,” we too
> conclude that Villavicencio‐Serna has not shown enough to entitle him
> to issuance of the writ. We therefore affirm.

Comment: Yes. Clearly the witnesses were lying. But we’re they lying in court or were they lying when they recanted?

Comment: In _Stickland v. Washington_, 466 U.S. 668, 686 (1984) there was a finding that the right to counsel, in a broader term, means that a criminally accused person is entitled to a just outcome. Maybe this finding is narrow enough to be only applicable on the duties imposed on counsel, but I would expect that a fair-trial-related right should come to the same conclusion. Maybe, based on Dale M's insight, at least the right to be heard again automatically and vacating the previous ruling should result in a new trial could be achieved?

Comment: @kisspuska Nope. This is an actual, recently decided case precisely on point and it doesn't recognize that right.